# XAMPP + Subversion + TortoiseSVN + Eclipse

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, xampp

I've suffered enough hours trying to figure this out and get it working and I hope someone can shine some light on this issue.

In essence, I'm trying to install Subversion with XAMPP on my Windows XP machine as a Virtual Host and access the repository with TortoiseSVN and Ecplise installed on my MacBook via http://.

I've downloaded installed the following files:

- XAMPP Windows 1.7.3
- Subversion 1.6.6

After installing XAMPP, I've setup the proper DNS routing so that I can see the website externally and able to access it through http:// web.mydomain.com.

Now I want to setup http:// svn.mydomain.com to access my repository via virtual host through apache.

First, I edited the C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts and added the following:

`127.0.0.1 svn.mydomain.com`

Then, following the tutorials on how to install Subversion with apache and I did the following:

Created the repository located in C:\xampp\svn.

Copied the mod_authz_svn.so and mod_dav_svn.so to C:\xampp\apache\modules.

Edited the C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf and added LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so and LoadModule authz_svn_module modules/mod_authz_svn.so to the end of the LoadModules list.

Edited the C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf modified and added the following:

```
NameVirtualHost *

< VirtualHost * >
    ServerName svn.mydomain.com

    <Location />
       DAV svn
       SVNParentPath "C:/xampp/svn"
    </Location>
< /VirtualHost >
```

Then I restarted Apache with no problems.

I was able to access the repository through http:// svn.mydomain.com/repository through a browser and also through TortoiseSVN, so far so good.

The real problem is when i try to import a new project to the repository through TortoiseSVN. I get the following error: "Could not open the requested SVN filesystem."

I hope someone can help! Thanks!!!

Comment: Not to disparage your efforts, but have you ever considered using another version control system, if this is mostly just for personal use between your computers? For instance, Mercurial and Bazaar both have really easy-to-setup build-in web serving capabilities that let you skip most of the hassle.

Comment: what is the error message in the apache log file? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its likely to be permissions problem. But you will need to look in your apache error log for more specific information on this error. 
Being able to access via a browser only confirms read access, while an import is a write operation. So you need to check on the access permissions. 
If you can add more information on what the error logs say, perhaps someone may be able to provide more information and help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue in svn but I have solved it. Generally this problem happens when you have created repo without specify the `fs-type`. So define the `fs-type` at the time when you create your svn repository like:

`svnadmin.exe create --fs-type fsfs C:/xampp/svn`